# Syntax Coloring in LaTeX

Tags: listings, packages, highlighting, minted, syntax

Is there any way to include Python code in a LaTeX file and automatically color its syntax? Is it possible to do syntax coloring with any other language? If yes what packages can I use to do that?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/213217/convert-html-to-image

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to use the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. It allows a wide range of formatting for the output, can choose to display only part of an input file and so on. The package also comes with a number of predefined languages it understands, including Python.

Comment: Listings is nice and I use it a lot- but it is getting a little long in the tooth.  The last update was in 2007.

Comment: Well, LaTeX2e was release in 1994 :-) I believe that there is some testing going on with a new version, although news has been sporadic.

Comment: Elaborating a bit on Sharpie's comment -- the Listings v.1 package can't really change very much at all without breaking backwards compatibility, so there isn't much updating that can be done other than relatively minor bug-fixes.  (I say this as the current maintainer, who is embarrassed to be so far behind on these "minor" bug-fixes, but unfortunately the fixes are far less minor than the bugs.)  The original author has mentioned a v.2 of the Listings package, about a year ago, but I know of no more recent news.

Comment: Is listings defunct? The link seems dead

Comment: @soandos Link fixed

Answer (score 48):

While `listings` package is good, it has some deficiencies, especially in Unicode support. I'd recommend trying out [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/), which uses the output of [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), which is more likely to get grammar updates than `listings`.

Comment: This package is awesome. Plus, it's made by a fellow SO-er: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966425/source-code-highlighting-in-latex/1985330#1985330.

Comment: If I just had time to push a new release already … :-( At the moment, it still has got quite a few problems.

Comment: Yeah, it's great, I particularly like code coloring straight out of the box and Scala support.

Answer (score 6):

I use matlab code in my papers. To get syntax coloring in matlab, put the following in the header:

```
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\definecolor{string}{rgb}{0.7,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{comment}{rgb}{0.13,0.54,0.13}
\definecolor{keyword}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1.0}
```

Then use the [`highlight.m`](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/highlight/) function in matlab to generate the code to put in the latex file.

Then just enclose the matlab code inside

```
\begin{alltt}
%% code generated by highlight.m %%
\end{alltt}
```

Comment: Mark up code using either PRE HTML blocks or by indenting with four spaces. Or online with back ticks.

Comment: Consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 5):

Another package to consider is [`fancyvrb`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb).  It is a bit more general than `listings` as it provides an expanded verbatim environment where listings focuses specifically on formatting source code- this means you can pull some tricks with `listings` that are not possible with `fancyvrb`.  However, `fancyvrb` is the package used by the [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) documentation generator to highlight source code in PDF output.

If you are documenting some Python code, you may want to look into using Sphinx anyway- it is the bee's knees.

Another package that looks promising is [`minted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted).  This package allows you to format code using [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) which is a very sophisticated syntax highlighter written in Python.

Comment: fancyvrb is nice. With time I lean towards minimalist highlighting, but I still need some basic formatting support. Depending on the case, I also use listings with a very simple configuration (just tt, and serif italic for comments or meta-syntactic stuff).

Answer (score 4):

For technical documentation my preferred method is to use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/contents.html).  The output LaTeX looks ugly (well, machine generated) but the output looks nice.  It uses Pygments behind the scenes.

I've not used `minted`, but from what people say it should work just as well, and allow you to author a LaTeX document.  (But if you use Sphinx, you'll get HTML and other outputs.  They're working on epub.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code I made to put listings of results and code in some homework i turned in recently. Results and code listings each get their own counter so they are numbered, and my paper can reference them.

Here's the stuff for the header:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb, listings, color}

\definecolor{gogetit}{HTML}{6C8B9F}
\lstset{
    fancyvrb=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=3,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\textbf,
    identifierstyle=,
    commentstyle=\color{gogetit}\textit,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    }
\begin{document}
\fvset{numbers=left,numbersep=3pt,fontsize=\small,fontfamily=helvetica,frame=lines,resetmargins=true}
```

Now, throughout my paper I include results from estimations without any language defined

```
\newcounter{resultsin}
\setcounter{resultsin}{1}
\VerbatimInput[firstline=6,lastline=27,label=\fbox{\textbf{Results \arabic{resultsin}:} OLS labor supply}]{"./results/ps3_stata_c.log"}
\stepcounter{resultsin}
```

And at the end I change the language to R to show some code

```
\section*{Appendix: Code}
\lstset{language=R}
\newcounter{codein}
\setcounter{codein}{1}
\VerbatimInput[firstline=70,lastline=90,label=\fbox{\textbf{Code \arabic{codein}:} function for IV estimation}]{"ps3.R"}
\stepcounter{codein}
\VerbatimInput[firstline=42,lastline=53,label=\fbox{\textbf{Code \arabic{codein}:} makeresiduals (called by IVregress)}]{"ps3.R"}
\stepcounter{codein}
\VerbatimInput[firstline=53,lastline=58,label=\fbox{\textbf{Code \arabic{codein}:} addcons (called by IVregress)}]{"ps3.R"}
```