# How best to include programming source code in LaTeX documents?

Tags: highlighting, listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax Coloring in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex)

I'm relatively new to LaTeX, and am starting to use it for academic paper writing. I'm doing a lot of computer programming as part of my academic work, so need to be able to include code extracts easily.

I know I can easily make them appear in a monospaced font, but what would you suggest for getting automatic syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As the original developer of **[`minted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted)**, that’s of course what I recommend.

It uses Pygments to produce beautifully coloured code, e.g.:

[image]

On the other hand, I realize that installing `minted` isn’t trivial, and it relies on an external program. Simpler, more efficient (very noticeable for a large number of code fragments!) and already installed on most systems – but also less versatile than `minted` – is the package `listings`. (Furthermore, `listings` has a nice feature to break over-long lines automatically and indent them correctly. `minted` can’t do this.)

Comment: I have install both minted and pygmentize (v1.2.2), whenever I try to compile a document using minted, I get the following error message : ! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.

However, I can run pygmentize fine from any command prompt. What is going on?

Comment: @JCL: That’s a bug in the current version. Get the latest version from the trunk of the repository at http://minted.googlecode.com/hg/minted.sty. Additionally, Windows may make problem. It’s not a supported platform at the moment (since I don’t have it – I can’t troubleshoot Windows problems).

Comment: After rebooting I got it working, but I don't seem to be able to use Unicode characters, is that normal?

Comment: @JCL: Only XeTeX really supports Unicode characters. I didn’t get fancyvrb set up properly to support UTF-8 in plain pdfTeX.

Comment: The link for minted is broken. You can find it [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) and [here](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) now.

Answer (score 13):

Use package `listings`. But there are other options see: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-codelist.