# Package for displaying source code

Tags: packages, formatting, algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How best to include programming source code in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/how-best-to-include-programming-source-code-in-latex-documents)

What is a good way to display program source like c++/lisp code in a latex document?

Comment: There are many questions on this site that deal with this. You should search.

Comment: Duplicate of [How best to include programming source code in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/how-best-to-include-programming-source-code-in-latex-documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see package `listings`=> run `texdoc listings`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package.