# Typesetting C functions

Tags: typography

I want to describe C-functions in a document, e.g.:

`The function fooBar() does foo and bar...`

Should I use a different typeset for the function in the text? I have the feeling that for example `\textsc{fooBar()}` highlights the function in the text, but for a high cost in appearance.

Comment: You can use `listings` package.

Comment: If you just want some unique formatting for code, I personally would use `\texttt{fooBar()}`, which uses a monospaced font.

Comment: Looks fantastic ChrisS!

Comment: Close voters, if anything this is a duplicate rather than off topic.  [Writing source code in LaTeX as text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167714)  See also [Package for displaying source code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7614)

Comment: As a combination of the comments of H. Kumar and ChriS: You can use `\lstinline{fooBar()}` to typeset it as some piece of code appearing somewhere in your text, e.g. even with logical markup.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I agree with you, if closed, it should be done so for the correct reason: being a duplicate, but not off-topic, in my point of view.

Comment: You can even (with `listings` for instance) ask Latex to use one character to “delimit” those parts of code, e.g., `The function |fooBar()| does foo and bar…`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal in different ways. One is to use teletype family fonts `\texttt{foobar()}` as chrisS has mentioned in the comments. These are fixed-width fonts. Another option, is to use `\emph{foobar()}` style. Although in normal text `'\emph{}` seems to be italic, but it is actually more than that. For example, if your text is italic and you use `\emph{foobar()}` for your function, latex makes it visually distinct by making it normal text. In short, `\emph{}` guarantees a visual distinction but it is not necessary always pleasing.

[image]

Image from [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).

My suggestion would be to define a macro of your own such as

```
\newcommand{\MyCode}[1]{%
\texttt{#1}}
```

And you it like `The function \MyCode{fooBar()} does foo and bar...`

This one has the advantage that in case you decide `texttt` is not what you want, you can change only your macro definition and the effect will apply to your whole document.

For longer pieces of the code, there are packages like `listings` that can you you with typesetting of different languages (e.g. [this Q/A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81834/whats-the-best-way-to-typeset-c-codes-in-latex)).