# What is the simpliest way to make a documentation from code

Tags: templates, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How best to include programming source code in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/how-best-to-include-programming-source-code-in-latex-documents)

suppose a file with code (*.cpp, *.php, or whatever). There's a lot of symbols like '$', '{', '}' what will definetely be disliked by TeX. I want to make a documentation from a code file. Maybe you heard of some templates for working with code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Search the site and you will find lots of relevant info. Check the `listings` package

Comment: IMHO the `refman` class is very useful for technical documentation, so it might be a starting point. As pmav99 said, the `listings` package will also help you to output code with a fancy syntax highlighting. `:-)` That said, I usually prefer to use an external tool to generate my code documentation in the LaTeX format, e.g., Doxygen or Sphinx, because I can keep both `doc` and `src` sync'ed. `:-)`

Comment: Just for reference look here for other packages http://www.ctan.org/keyword/computer_code. This is a common question that has been covered before (almost a FAQ). Perhaps it should be closed.