# Typesetting LaTeX Source Code with the listings package

Tags: listings, syntax, highlighting

I am writing some documentation for a LaTeX package, in which I am going to be including some example LaTeX code.  What is the best way to typeset that code?  I know I could just use `verbatim`, but it would be nice to get syntax highlighting.  I realize that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/how-display-latex-code-in-latex-document), in which the consensus was to use the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.  The problem with `listings` is that it seems to only have a driver for TeX, not LaTeX.  For example, when I typeset something like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX,
                   keywordstyle=\bfseries,
                   identifierstyle=\itseries,
                   stringstyle=\ttfamily]
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
  This is a test!
\end{minipage}
\end{lstlisting}
```

it results in something like this:

> \*begin*{*minipage*}{\**hsize**}
>     *This is a test!*
>   \**end**{*center*}

which is obviously messed up.

Is there a LaTeX-specific driver for `listings`?  If not, is there another package that does syntax highlighting for LaTeX code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to give the 'sub-language' for TeX:

```
language = [LaTeX]{TeX}
```

As you are writing a package, you might also want to use the `moretexcs` key to add 'new' LaTeX commands. For example, in my [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) I have very long list:

```
  moretexcs    = 
    {
      addto,
      ampere,
      ang,
      angstrom,
      ...
```

to cover all of the new macros it adds, plus ones from other packages that are in the documentation and are not known to `listings`.

Answer (score 11):

[`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) uses the [pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/) interpreter, which understands TeX, so this might be a valid option.

Comment: The problem with using `minted` is that this document is going to be distributed as a `.dtx` and many users won't have `minted` installed (and will thereby not be able to compile the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, another solution using the [pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/) interpreter is [texments](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/texments/)