# Write LaTeX with LaTeX

Tags: verbatim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typesetting LaTeX Source Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/typesetting-latex-source-code)

Hi all, i would like to know suggestions on how can I write an explicative text of LaTeX using LaTeX.
Till now I use `\verb!SomeLatexinstruction!` when i need to write an instruction.
There are other solutions, that looks more elegantly?

Comment: Duplicate of [Typesetting LaTeX Source Code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/typesetting-latex-source-code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see package `listings`=> run `texdoc listings`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the shortvrb package, too. For example `\MakeShortVerb{|}` will offer the notation |SomeLaTeXinstruction|.

Answer (score 2):

The [minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show some LaTeX code side by side with its output, the [showexpl](http://ctan.org/pkg/showexpl) package may be of some use here.