# Any way to show LaTeX example code *and* execute it?

Tags: listings, verbatim, documentation

In (La)TeX documentation and tutorials, it is common to show a snippet of code next to the output it generates. It might be two minipages side by side, or a code listing followed by boxed output, or whatever. For a trivial example, we might see

`\[ sin \theta \]` next to its output, *sin* θ

Whenever I've done this, I had to use two copies of the code, e.g., once inside `verbatim` and once inside a minipage or framed box). This just begs for inconsistencies and maintainability problems, since it's very easy to fix one copy and not the other. So, **is there any way to display a bunch of code *and* to execute (a copy of) it, showing the results?**

I'm pretty sure it's not straightforward: the code needs to have different catcodes for reading and displaying, but catcodes get assigned only once, when the text is encountered. But if there's no better way, it should be doable by reading the code verbatim and saving a copy in the `.aux` file, from where it'll get read and interpreted the next time around. But I've never seen such a thing. Has anyone else here?

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19295/5764); [Typesetting LaTeX Source Code with the listings package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5903/5764)

Comment: @Werner: `tcolorbox` is new ;-)

Comment: @Werner, only the first of these questions is related. The second is about styling LaTeX in `listings`

Comment: I had no luck bringing up these questions when I looked, how do you guys do it... but I think @Marco's answer is better than the ones in the linked question :-)

Comment: See [CTAN topic macro-demo](https://ctan.org/topic/macro-demo) for a list of all alternatives offering that functionality.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both packages provide options to manipulated the output. The options demonstrate the default behaviour.

**Option 1:** Package [`showexpl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showexpl)

This method uses the the package `listings`. The manipulation is done with LaTeX commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
$1+1=2$
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option 2:** Package [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

This package uses `listings` to format the code and TikZ to draw the frame. Based on this you have a lot of options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
1+1=2
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{items.tex}

\input{items.tex}
\end{document}
```

where `items.tex` has something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Clever, thanks, but I'm afraid it's pretty impractical with lots of code snippets. Fortunately there _are_ better solutions already :-)