# display both an image and a code, side-by-side

Tags: graphics, listings, two-column

I'd like to display both an image and a code using pdflatex, side-by-side to illustrate a concept. The code uses listing package.

How could I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Should be simple enough using a `minipage`; do you have any code that you post to show us what you've tried? :)

Comment: You are probably looking for [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19295/5764) and/or [Any way to show LaTeX example code *and* execute it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110349/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to display an image with its corresponding source code, then the [showexpl](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) package might be what you are looking for.

But since I suspect you just want to use any picture next to some code, then I sugest using the `minipage` environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{lstlisting}
 Some code.
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \includegraphics{some_picture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

which yields the following output:

[image]

Of course, you can then adjust the parameters of the `minipage` as you see fit, but I find this basic structure to be sufficient.

Note that you *can't* put a float inside the minipage environment. For more information, see [How to use figure inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage)

Hope it helps!