# How to show latex commands in text mode

Tags: math-mode, verbatim, output, text-mode

Sorry for the basic question.
What I want to do is to show the `LaTeX` command and, right after that, the output. But how can I show `LaTeX` formulas without obtaining errors for not using the math mode environment.

The problem is if I put the `$...$`, the formula appears and not the command. If I dont use the `$...$` I get an error.

I have tried also to put inside a `\text{}`. No good either.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `verbatim` package?

Comment: You can try `\verb!<code for formula>!`. If you want syntax highlighting then use `listings` package.

Comment: Use `\verb+latex_code+`.

Comment: I guess http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110349/any-way-to-show-latex-example-code-and-execute-it/110350#110350 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/ may be of interest.

Comment: The proper solution to this is [the `showexpl` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) as per the links of @TorbjørnT's comment.  That way you don't have to duplicate the code.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240317/how-can-i-typeset-an-environment-and-its-literal-equivalent-in-an-environment and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it

Answer (score 16):

You can use `\verb` as

```
\verb!$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$!
```

Or better use `listings` package

```
\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX},basicstyle=\ttfamily]{$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
Using \verb|\verb|:

\verb!$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$! \quad $\longrightarrow$ \quad $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$


Using \verb|listings|:

\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX},basicstyle=\ttfamily]{$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$} \quad $\longrightarrow$ \quad $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `\latexcode` macro is ingenious. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be robust to the inclusion of instructions such as `\sin` in its argument. E.g., the instruction `\latexcode{$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$}` produces the error message `! Improper alphabetic constant.` (No such error occurs when using `\verb|...|`.) Can your code by generalized to include this example application?

Comment: @Mico Yes, there is some problem. Unfortunately I can't debug it now. Hence I retracted the code. Thanks for testing :)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this can meet your spectations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\gfcb}[1]{%
    \fcolorbox{white}{gray!10!}{\quad\strut #1\quad}
    } % gfcb := gray fcolorbox
\newcommand{\cop}[1]{%
    \gfcb{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}} 
    \ensuremath{\quad\longrightarrow\quad #1}
    } % cop := code output

\begin{document}

% Examples of usage

\cop{\ln x} \\

\cop{\sin x} \\

\cop{4\cdot a^n} \\

\cop{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\

\cop{\displaystyle\int\cot^2 x\,dx} \\

\cop{\overline x=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}} \\

\cop{\displaystyle\lim_{\lVert \Delta x\rVert\to0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_i)\Delta x_i} \\

\cmdc{f(x)=\begin{cases}
x-4 & \text{if } x\leq 4 \\
x^3 & \text{if } x>4
\end{cases}} \\

\end{document}
```

I casually made it a couple of months ago when I had the same question while I was wondering how to display a command and its output for a `LaTeX` potential manual. And surfing TeX.SE I have just met this question.

[image]

The issue I got is that the code input can only be displayed in one line, so for big equations, that would not look good and would not fit the width of the page or paragraph.

[image]

**UPDATE**

In case you need to show large equations, you can use a `tcolorbox` that displays a code listing and its output.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{tcolorbox.doc.s_main}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\definecolor{midnightBlue}{RGB}{25,25,112}
\definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}

\begin{document}

\DeclareTCBListing{mybox}{ s O{} m }{%
colback=blue!10!,
colframe=webblue,
bicolor,
colframe=midnightBlue,
colbacklower=white,
after title={\hfill Output},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
IfBooleanTF={#1}
{text side listing}{listing side text},
title=#3,#2}

% Tcolobox with title
\begin{mybox}{Code}
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x-4 & \text{if } x\leq 4 \\
x^3 & \text{if } x>4
\end{cases}$
\end{mybox}

% Tcolorbox without title
\begin{mybox}{}
$P(k):2(k+1)-3\leq2(k+1)-2$
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cll}
   \begin{minipage}{3cm}
   \begin{verbatim}
      \ln x
   \end{verbatim} \end{minipage} & $\longrightarrow$ & 
  lnx\\
  \begin{minipage}{2cm}
  \begin{verbatim}
 4 \cdot a^n
  \end{verbatim} \end{minipage} & $\longrightarrow$ &
  $4 \cdot a^{n}$\\
 \begin{minipage}{2cm}
 \begin{verbatim}
  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
 \end{verbatim} \end{minipage} & $\longrightarrow$ & 
 $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$\\
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This has no packages. You have a lot of freedom to modify it. I am sure that you will enjoy it.