# How can I execute LaTeX code inside LaTeX code?

Tags: tables, pdftex, positioning

I am writing [a book](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook). There are plenty of different examples of codes and on the other side of a page it displays the result of code. Sometimes I cannot compile my code and just put an image as a result of code, despite the fact that I compress all images as much as I can. It is a kind of wasting memory, so I would like to optimize the size of the book.

Is it possible somehow execute LaTeX code inside LaTeX code and see the final result? I expect something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{qqq}

\begin{document}

    \begin{run_latex}
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{qqq}
        \begin{document}
        qqq
        \end{document}
    \end{run_latex}

\end{document}
```

***Here is my MWE:***

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible,
frame=single, breaklines=true, postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{ Aligning equations inbetween text}
\begin{tabular}{l | c}
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.4\textwidth}
RESULT OF EXECUTED CODE\textbf{}
\end{minipage}
& \begin{minipage}[m]{0.5\textwidth}
\renewcommand\textminus{\mbox{-}}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\intertext{Photochemical:}
K_{UV} &: M[1]& &\ch{-> M^{*}}[1]
\intertext{Catalyzed:}
K_I &: I& &\ch{->} 2R \\
K_S &: R + M [1]& &\ch{-> RM^{*}}[1]
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One hacky idea (which I couldn’t get to work myself): Inside an environment, locally redefine the commands `\begin` and `\end` to do the usual thing, unless their argument is `document`, in which case they should simply do nothing. Also redefine `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` to do nothing. Then everything should work, as long as the relevant packages have already been loaded in the preamble.

Comment: Have a look at the [Multi-file LaTeX projects](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects). While not 100% your answer, it might bepossible to adapt other files and simply input them to the main file.

Comment: Thank You all for your answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility: the tcolorbox package

For easier examples, it can directly display the output.

For full documents, including a documentclass, packages etc., this will internally produce a pdf of the output and include the pdf. As this is a vector graphic, it shouldn't increase the document size too much (needs to be compiled with shell-escape enabled).

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\tcbset{sidebyside}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\intertext{Photochemical:}
K_{UV} &: M[1]& &\ch{-> M^{*}}[1]
\intertext{Catalyzed:}
K_I &: I& &\ch{->} 2R \\
K_S &: R + M [1]& &\ch{-> RM^{*}}[1]
\end{alignat*}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{
listing and comment,
pdf comment,
freeze pdf,
compilable listing,
run pdflatex,
}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
qqq
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, but the code works in overleaf and doesn't on my machine =(. 3 errors like that: ```LaTeX Error: Environment tcbraster undefined. [\end{tcblisting}]```.  Also I changed ```most``` to ```listings``` (it causes more errors for me)

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh This sounds very suspicious. What tex distribution do you use? texlive, miktex or something else? A package should normally be installed as a whole. That parts of it are missing is very strange!

Comment: I am on linux and the command ```pdflatex --version``` shows that I'm using ```pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)```

Comment: Do you have a full installation or just some  of the linux packaged chunks installed?

Comment: Yes, it shows ```texlive-full is already the newest version (2021.20220204-1).```

Comment: Very strange. Maybe ask a separate question about this issue to get the eyes of some linux users on it? (personally I never use the linux texlive packages and always install a vanilla texlive)

Comment: Yes, thank You very much one more time

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh You're welcome!

Comment: I fixed it! (aded to my sublime settings ```"options": ["--shell-escape"]```) Thank you for the answer!

Comment: and one more question: What I have to do to show only result without code?

Comment: `text only` or `comment only` -- depending on which type you use

Answer (score 0):

Also as a [variant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110349/any-way-to-show-latex-example-code-and-execute-it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
$1+1=2$
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]