# How print the latex commands in document with line numbers in a coloured box

Tags: input, colorbox, command-line

I want to write the latex commands in the document ina coloured box with line numbers. Much like in here the latex commands display in a gray coloured box. I want that with line numbers. And also i want not be limited in grey colour. I want to use my own colur combination. And the line numbers would in different coloured box and the commands should be in a different coloured  box. It is not needed to separate the lines with an horizontal line. [image]

Comment: Try `minted` package. Overleaf has an intro to `minted`: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typesetting LaTeX Source Code with the listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/typesetting-latex-source-code-with-the-listings-package)