# Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file

Tags: package-writing, dtx

When documenting a style file, it would be nice to be able to easily put side by side different examples of code, side-by-side with the output they produce.

What recommendations to people have to do this efficiently, and æsthetically?

Comment: I think it has been asked by others. See this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/how-display-latex-code-in-latex-document/6533#6533

Comment: @xport: that's a question about just showing the source-code. Mine is somewhat more precise in that it requires side-by-side displaying of LaTeX code, and Seamus' answer happens to suggest the same tool as the answer you've linked to.

Comment: @xport: That question is not a duplicate, but I see that your answer is relevant here. However, DTX files must be handled different here because of there special handling of `%`. These must first be removed from the start of the code lines, but remaining ones must be handled as comments again when processing the output...

Comment: Also related: [Any way to show LaTeX example code *and* execute it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110349/any-way-to-show-latex-example-code-and-execute-it)

Comment: See [CTAN topic macro-demo](https://ctan.org/topic/macro-demo) for a list of all alternatives offering that functionality.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's [`showexpl`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) which has the `LTXexample` environment for exactly this purpose. It's based on `listings`

Comment: I was going to answer recommending the same package; while I was designing a little example you beat me!

Comment: I tried to use `showexpl` quite a while ago for my DTX files and it had issues with the special handling of `%` in these files. I can't remember the exact details now, but I gave up on it and coded something by myself as part of my `ydoc` class (which is still an unstable alpha version).

Comment: @Martin I've only ever used it in normal `.tex` files, not in `.dtx` files, and I've not encountered any (serious) problems. If you could add an answer about `ydoc` I'm sure people would be interested in it.

Comment: @Gonzalo For these "low-hanging fruit" questions you need to be quick on the draw... Heh. You beat me to the sections/chapter headings one, so I guess we're even...

Comment: @Seamus: The issue is that `ydoc` is not really finished yet and has almost no documentation. I didn't do much on that part of the code for over a year and have issues recalling its current state. ;-)

Comment: @Martin but if there are issues with `showexpl` for `.dtx` writers (which is what this question is about) then even the unstable `ydoc` might be better. It's surely worth a mention at least!

Comment: @Martin: the problems with `showexpl`... I assume the problem is only with comments in the sample code being displayed itself, am I right?

Comment: @Niel: `docstrip` requires all documentation lines to start with a `%` and `showexpl` takes these verbatim. Also, while compiling the documentation all `%` are ignored, which will print all comments in the example code.

Comment: @Martin: I'm familiar with the stripping of `%` out of the documentation, which is of course the context in which I'll be using `showexpl`; for the time being I may be able to deal with example code that contains no comments. However, now I'm more concerned about your remarks about `showexpl` taking the comments of the documentation lines verbatim: wouldn't the functionality of `showexpl` only be engaged when all of the `%` characters have been stripped anyhow?

Comment: @Niel: Normally yes, but in the DTX file `%` are not comment characters but instead ignored.

Comment: @Martin: I'm just going to take that to mean that the only problems I am likely to have, is that `docstrip` will stymie any attempts to have comments in the content of a `LTXexample` environment. I was concerned that you were hinting at additional problems.

Answer (score 39):

My package [tcolorbox](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) provides another possible answer for the question. It allows to place the source code before or after the output. With version 2.20, source and output can be set side-by-side. The output can be placed inside a colored box or outside, before the source or after the source.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins,listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{exampleA}[2][]{%
  colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black,
  colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,
  coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!white,
  bicolor,colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  sidebyside,
  title=#2,#1}

\newtcblisting{exampleB}[2][]{%
  colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!white,
  bicolor,colbacklower=red!50!yellow!5!white,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  sidebyside,text and listing,
  title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{exampleA}[righthand width=3.5cm,center lower]{Side-by-side (inside box)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleA}

\begin{exampleA}[righthand width=3.5cm,listing outside text]{Side-by-side (outside box)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleA}

\begin{exampleB}[lefthand width=3.5cm]{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleB}

\begin{exampleB}[lefthand width=3.5cm,text outside listing,
  colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,
  arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,watermark text=Source,
  watermark color=yellow!75!red!30!white]{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried this approach.  It is magnificent!  Whereas some of the other methods choke on my code (probably because I do internal catcode changes), yours sails right through.  And I like how it auto-wraps as well.  Wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: @Thomas F. Sturm: what does `title=#2,#1` stand for?. If I want to use only one style, how the command `\newtcblisting{exampleA}[2][]` needs to be modified?

Comment: @user149418 `title=#2,#1` stands for setting the title to the mandatory parameter `#2` and adding further options from the optional parameter `#1`. If no title and no further options are needed, use `\newtcblisting{exampleA}{colframe=...`

Answer (score 28):

I made a package `tkzexample` that I use for all my documentation. I upload yesterday on ctan a new version (you need to wait several days before see it) but without documentation actually ( I have a little work to do  to finish the doc. The main macro is based on the `\codeexample`of T. Tantau. Till gave me permission to use and modify the macro. 
`\codeexample` don't work with accents and utf8 but `tkzexample` accepts accents and utf8. I add the possibility to num the lines and I created an option to save the example on an extern file with `\usepackage[saved]{tkzexample}`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tkzexample} 
% possible \usepackage[saved]{tkzexample} permet de sauvegarder l'exemple
\usepackage[protrusion = true,
            expansion, final,
            verbose = false, babel   = true]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = T1, family = tt*}  

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\colorlet{graphicbackground}{blue!10!white}%
\colorlet{codebackground}{red!10}%  
1) How to use

 \begin{tkzltxexample}[]
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkzexample}
\begin{document}     
\begin{tkzexample}[]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path coordinate (A) at (0,0)
          coordinate (B) at (-60:12cm)
          coordinate (C) at (240:12cm);
\foreach \density in {20,30,...,160}{%
    \draw[fill=MidnightBlue!\density] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \path (A) coordinate (X) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.15](A)
          -- (C) coordinate[pos=.15](B) -- (X) coordinate[pos=.15](C);}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{tkzexample}
\end{document}  
\end{tkzltxexample} 

2) Usage classique

\begin{tkzexample}[latex=6cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \path coordinate (A) at (0,0)
          coordinate (B) at (-60:12cm)
          coordinate (C) at (240:12cm);
    \foreach \density in {20,30,...,160}{%
        \draw[fill=MidnightBlue!\density] 
             (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
        \path (A) coordinate (X)
           -- (B) coordinate[pos=.15](A)
           -- (C) coordinate[pos=.15](B)
           -- (X) coordinate[pos=.15](C);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{tkzexample}
3) Un tableau
\begin{tkzexample}[width=6cm,frame tex=Maroon,frame code=Maroon,num ]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule  
Essai avec un tabeau  &\\
\midrule
Un premier &   texte\\
Un second & texte\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tkzexample} 

4) Les accents en français
\begin{tkzexample}[small,num]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] {éè§çà};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tkzexample} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I shall have to check it out. Nice eye-candy!

Comment: Thanks!. I will put on my site the new version this week and a beta version of the documentation. The version on ctan will arrive in several days because I uploaded a lot of stuff.

Comment: @Niel The announcement is not done yet but the new version in on CTAN. The collection tkz is also on CTAN and on TeXLive 2011. TL 2010 is now frozen so you need to install the package by hand Otherwise you'll wait for the TL2011 ( the beginning of July)

Answer (score 12):

For normal documents the `showexpl` package would be the way to go, as Seamus already stated in his answer. However, special care must be taken for DTX files because of the special handling of `%` in them.

I wrote some own code for the my `ydoc` bundle. The `ydoc-expl` package of this bundle provides an `example` float where the actual code is wrapped into `examplecode`. You can add a caption and also display a list of examples. It uses `listings` and `float` for this. You can use `\lstset{...}` to modify its display. Its sets the compiled output on the left or top and the code on the right or bottom depending on the amount of horizontal space both require.

Note that `ydoc` is still an alpha version and under development. Things might change in future revisions and there a still a few bugs in it.

You can use the `ydoc` class instead of `ltxdoc` or just load the `ydoc-expl` package.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
% Copyright (C) 2009 by Martin Scharrer <martin@scharrer-online.de>
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2008/05/04 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Martin Scharrer.
%
% This work consists of the files j.dtx, j.ins
% and the derived file j.sty.
%
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{ydoc-expl}
%\documentclass{ydoc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\EnableCrossrefs
%\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
%\OnlyDescription
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
  \PrintChanges
  %\newpage\PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% {Titlepage ..}
% \listof{example}{List of Examples}
%
% \section{Usage}
% \begin{example}
%    \begin{examplecode}
%       \begin{tikzpicture}
%           \draw (2.5,2.5) circle (2cm);
%           \draw (0,0) -- (5,5);
%       \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{examplecode}
%    \caption{Some example}
% \end{example}
%
% \StopEventually{}
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
%
% \section{Implementation}
% \subsection{Package Header}
%
% \begin{macro}{\mymacro}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\mymacro{%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \Finale
%</package>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 11):

There are several packages for this purpose:

- `fvrb-ex`, based on [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), contributed with `fancyvrb` together.
- `lstdoc`, part of [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, used by document of `listings` itself.
- [`examplep`](http://ctan.org/pkg/examplep), based on `listings`.
- [`showexpl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showexpl), based on `listings`.
- [`sverb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sverb), provides `demo` environment.

And Martin may explain `ydoc` himself.

Comment: Nice list, but again: DTX files are more tricky then normal documents and these packages might not handle them correctly.

Comment: In my own document, I also wrote some macros using [`verbatim`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) package for myself. (I didn't know these packages that time.) It seems the function is implemented time and time again.

Comment: @Martin: At least `lstdoc.sty` works fine in DTX files. It is used in `listings.dtx`. However, it is not well documented.

Comment: It seems OK to use `fvrb-ex` (used in `fvrb-ex.dtx`) and `sverb` (used in `sverb.dtx`) in DTX files too.

Answer (score 5):

For documenting my own packages I wrote a custom class [`cnltx-doc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cnltx) which comes bundled with a package called `cnltx-example`:

```
\usepackage{cnltx-example}
```

or

```
\usepackage[example]{cnltx}
```

It provides an environment `{example}` which can display code and output side by side (for which there's also the `{sidebyside}` environment)) or above each other or only the code (for which there's also the `{sourcecode}` environment).

It allows for compiling the example as separate document if needed (with the engine of choice) – this needs `shell-escape` enabled at least for the first compilation, of course.

The package comes with predefined styles for LaTeX, BibTeX and makeindex listings. Output (colors, frames…) can be customized.

Behind the scenes the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cnltx-example}
\setcnltx{
  add-cmds = {foo}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  This is a \LaTeX\ example.

  \newcommand*\foo{foo}

  Some inline math $x^2$ and some display math:
  \begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
  \end{equation}
\end{example}

\begin{example}[side-by-side]
  This is a \LaTeX\ example.

  \newcommand*\foo{foo}

  Some inline math $x^2$ and some display math:
  \begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
  \end{equation}
\end{example}

\begin{example}[side-by-side,code-left=false]
  This is a \LaTeX\ example.

  \newcommand*\foo{foo}

  Some inline math $x^2$ and some display math:
  \begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
  \end{equation}
\end{example}

\newpage

\begin{example}[compile,graphics={trim={2cm 22cm 2cm 2cm},clip}]
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}

  This is a \LaTeX\ example.

  \newcommand*\foo{foo}

  Some inline math $x^2$ and some display math:
  \begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
  \end{equation}

  \end{document}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209600/5049 (which I had forgotten about)

Comment: In the second example, if we want to comment the option for a while, the first line of the code is removed. Try `\begin{example}%[side-by-side]`.

Comment: @Sigur yes, commenting on the first line is not allowed IIRC