# Repeating environment contents twice

Tags: environments, minted

I'm writing a document where I have many code blocks like so:

```
\begin{align}
d = \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 } 
\end{align}

\begin{minted}{latex}
d = \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }
\end{minted}
```

So the first line renders the latex code, and the second shows the source.  Is there any way of wrapping this whole thing in its own environment?  For example, it would look like:

```
\begin{eqnexample}
d = \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }
\end{eqnexample}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: [showexpl](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19296/15717) may be of help

Comment: The source code of the minted documentation shows how this can be done.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest thing is to write out the contents of your "example" environment and read it back twice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted} % loads fancyvrb

\newenvironment{eqnexample}
 {\VerbatimOut{\jobname.tmp}}
 {\endVerbatimOut
  \inputminted{latex}{\jobname.tmp}
  \input{\jobname.tmp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnexample}
\begin{align}
  d &= \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }
  \\
  e &= 0
\end{align}
\end{eqnexample}

\begin{eqnexample}
\begin{multline}
  d = \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }
  \\
  = f(x,x')
\end{multline}
\end{eqnexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg.  It leaves a "clunky" feeling in my stomach, but knowing that I can write all kinds of things to temp files and use them later is actually very powerful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple way to do it with `fancyvrb`.  This approach saves the environment content to an external file and then brings it back twice.  There may be ways to do this without using a temporary external file, but if you are using `minted` you are already using lots of temporary files.

By the way, you might want to use the `upquote` package to make the prime on the *x* be a straight quote rather than a curly quote in the `minted` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage{fancyvrb} %Already loaded by minted

\newenvironment{eqnexample}%
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{eqnexample.tmp}}%
  {\end{VerbatimOut}%
    \begin{align}%
    \input{eqnexample.tmp}%
    \end{align}%
    \inputminted{latex}{eqnexample.tmp}}


\begin{document}

\begin{eqnexample}
d = \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }
\end{eqnexample}

\end{document}
```