# How can I align frames vertically with option [frame=single] when using showexpl in LaTeX?

Tags: vertical-alignment, frame, showexpl

When I use the option `[frame=single]` for LTXexample, the frame around the LaTeX code gets poor vertical alignment with respect to the formatted output, especially for one-line coding.

How can we get the two frames to align vertically?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[frame=single,numbers=none]
\TeX
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that adding a `\hbox{}` or `\mbox{}` for the `\basicstyle` option in this post: [Displaying Examples Side By Side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151294/displaying-examples-side-by-side)

It works, although the heights of the two frames differ slightly, but it's acceptable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[frame=single, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\hbox{}, numbers=none]
\TeX{}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Different solutions using other packages can be found in this post: [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file)