# Boxed equation on the right and its verbatim on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, boxes, verbatim

How to write a verbatim form of an equation on the left and its output form on the right inside a box?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As well, I think that this has been asked before, but I'm unable to find the other post now...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19295/5764)

Answer (score 8):

With `tcolorbox` and the `listings` library you can show the verbatim form of your equation.
you have just to add `listing side text` in the option of `tcblisting` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing side text}
\[f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x - x^2}\]
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]