# minipage layout not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, adjustbox

I want to generate a document with graph at left and tikz code at the right. I try to use two minipage but it seems it always layout it as up and down. The minipage is 0.45\textwidth, why latex still can not put it side by side?

The example code as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\lstset{
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
breaklines=true,
language=TeX,
frame=single}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Current output by pdflatex as bleow:

[image]

Comment: Remove empty lines between them. If you leave an empty line a new paragraph is inserted there. Use `\hfill` between them, for example.

Comment: Looks like [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19295) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the `showexpl` package and use the `LTXexample` environment.

[image]

If you wish to have the code in an external file use the `\LTXinputExample` environment instead as the second example does in the MWE.

### Notes:

- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)
  was used to set up a file to read for this test case.
  It is not needed in you actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% <-- Commented to prevent overwrite of test.tex
\begin{filecontents*}{test.tex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [ultra thick, blue] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    breaklines=true,
    language=TeX,
    frame=single,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[
        width=0.6\linewidth, 
        backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!40},
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
        numbers=none
    ]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [ultra thick, blue] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{LTXexample}

\LTXinputExample[
        width=0.6\linewidth, 
        backgroundcolor=\color{green!40},
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
        numbers=none,
    ]{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but if I use \input{test.tikz} replace the tikzpicture, I will get "\input{test.tikz}" at the right, I wish the code at the right but not the command. any idea?

Comment: @Beatlej: Have updated the example to show how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, it's really good now. BTW, just now I see pgfplot gallery at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html. it really looks nice. do you know which package can get the same behavior?

Comment: @Beatlej: I am not sure I fully understand your question, but below each image is `.tex` file link that gives the entire `.tex` file and all the required packages. If that wasn't what you were asking I'd recommend you post a new question.