# Necessary package for "codeexample"

Tags: code

What is the necessary package for

```
 \begin{codeexample}[]

 \end{codeexample}
```

In latex?

When we use this?

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you have seen this command somewhere? However searching my local tree (or you could have used google)

```
$ grep -l codeexample /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*/*.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/abbrevs.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/attrib.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/compsci.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/lips.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/moredefs.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/newclude.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/titles.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/bugtracker.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-doc/tkzexample.sty
```

so the `frankenstein` and `tkzexample` packages both define an environment of that name.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the package `tkzexample.sty` does not actually define `codeexample`. It only refers to
`codeexample' in this comment:

```
 % The author of the original code 
 % of the environment 'codeexample' is Till Tantau
```

However, `tkzexample` includes the environment:

```
 \begin{tkzltxexample}
```

which appears to be similar.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkzexample} 


\colorlet{codeonlybackground}{red!10}% sets background for tkzltxexample

\begin{document}

This file started:

\begin{tkzltxexample}[]
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkzexample} 
\colorlet{codeonlybackground}{red!10}% sets background for tkzltxexample
\begin{document}
...
\end{tkzltxexample}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: Example of LaTeX document with highlighted code]

Note that the background color here is set via:

```
 \colorlet{codeonlybackground}{red!10}
```

The option `very small` is also useful.

```
\begin{tkzltxexample}[very small]
```

See also the answer of 
[@alain-matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file/19942)
for further information on displaying code and output in parallel.