# How can I create a command or environment that starts and stops verbatim?

Tags: macros, environments, verbatim

I am writing a simple LaTeX guide, aimed at editors of a student paper. The paper is for students of mathematics and physics at my university, and so we use LaTeX.

Anyways, I want to include lots of examples in the guide, but it has become a bit cumbersome. I am using the following format right now:

```
\hspace{20pt}
\begin{framed}
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{verbatim}
      Some code
    \end{verbatim}
    $\quad \Rightarrow$\\
    \mbox{}\\
      Some code
  \end{minipage}
\end{framed}
```

The line `` `Some code` '' Is first shown verbatim, and then put outside in order for it to compile completely, showing the output.

I wanted to simplify this into a single command, something like

```
\newcommand{\verandshow}{1}
{
\hspace{20pt}
\begin{framed}
   \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{verbatim}
      #1
    \end{verbatim}
    $\quad \Rightarrow$\\
    \mbox{}\\
      #1
  \end{minipage}
\end{framed}
}
```

but the `verbatim` environment messes everything up. The same goes for creating a new environment, and putting the `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` statements in each end.

I have heard of alternative ways of showing code, like `listings`and others, but they did not work all that well. And even if they did, a question remains unanswered, one that I haven't found a simple answer to, which is: How do you define a command or environment that puts arguments into a verbatim environment?

Comment: What does `did not work all that well` mean? Please have a look on the the `tcolorbox` package and its `listings` library. It does show latex code and it's output (for not too complicated code of course)

Comment: First it didn't look as good as I had hoped, but my main problem somehow had to do with inputenc. listings, in particular, didn't take kindly to certain Norwegian letters, and I don't want to go too far down the rabbit hole just to get some code examples to show.

Comment: with package fvrb-ex and fancyvrb.

Comment: Related (with examples for both tcolorbox and showexpl): [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file)

Answer (score 2):

This shows only a small amount of the `tcolorbox` and `listings` features:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing options={numbers=left},colback=green,arc=0mm,auto outer arc}
Some Code with math output: 

\[ E = mc^2 \]

\end{tcblisting}

% And now listing only

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=yellow,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,listing only}
Some Code with math output: \[ E = mc^2 \]

\end{tcblisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this is a neat way of presenting everything, it sort of misses the question I most wanted answered. How can I create a command that places the arguments in verbatim? How can one get around the fact that once you place the start of a verbatim, there is no way of placing anything in between it and the closer that doesn't get printed verbatim?

Comment: @Deltat: Verbatim content in command arguments is tricky ;-). It might be possible with `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\NewDocumentEnvironment` features