# Is there an alternative to tkzexample?

Tags: listings, examples

which packages can I use to display the latex code and the compilation result at the same time?

Comment: [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings), [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted), ...

Comment: You could take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file for some inspiration.

Answer (score 8):

I find the `tcolorbox` package with the `tcblisting` environment very handy to display the source and output at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={Birthday duck}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[cake]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]