# Wrap an environment

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, sourcecode

The following codes are taken from [source and output side-by-side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114582)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{exampleB}[2][]{%
  colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!white,
  bicolor,colbacklower=red!50!yellow!5!white,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  sidebyside,text and listing,
  title=#2,#1}

\newenvironment{cExample}{\begin{exampleB}[lefthand width=3.5cm,text outside listing,  colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,
  arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,watermark text=Source,
  watermark color=yellow!75!red!30!white]{}}{\end{exampleB}}

\let\baExample\exampleB
\let\eaExample\endexampleB
\newenvironment{aExample}   {\baExample[lefthand width=3.5cm,text outside listing,
  colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,
  arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,watermark text=Source,
  watermark color=yellow!75!red!30!white]{}}    {\eaExample}

\begin{document}

\begin{aExample}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{aExample}

%\begin{cExample}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{cExample}

\end{document}
```

The environment `aExample` works, but the environment`cExample` (uncomment the `begin/end` env lines) will throw an error

> Runaway argument?
>
> ! File ended while scanning use of \next.
>
> `<`inserted text`>`
>
> ```
>              \par
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment requires `verbatim` mode. Using `\begin{exampleB}` and `\end{exampleB}` confuses the parser. Just use `\exampleB` and `\endexampleB` (which is essentially what you did in `aExample`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{exampleB}[2][]{%
  colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!white,
  bicolor,colbacklower=red!50!yellow!5!white,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  sidebyside,text and listing,
  title=#2,#1}

\newenvironment{cExample}{%
  \exampleB[
    lefthand width=3.5cm,
    text outside listing,
    colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    arc=0mm,
    boxrule=1pt,
    watermark text=Source,
    watermark color=yellow!75!red!30!white
  ]{}%
}{\endexampleB}

\begin{document}

\begin{cExample}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
\path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
\foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
{\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{cExample}

\end{document}
```

[image]