# Rename an environment: the codeexample used in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, sourcecode

I try to rename environment `codeexample` used in tikz document, but fail to use the tricks as in [Wrap an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501275).

This is related to [tkzexample: source and output side-by-side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19942/193369). The [pgfmanual-en-macros.tex](https://github.com/maxchendt/maxchendt.github.io/raw/master/files/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex) is used in `\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex}`  (I do not know how to minimize it and upload as a attachment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tkzexample} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.25cm,right=2.25cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead]{geometry}%pgfmanual-en-main-preamble.tex

\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex}
\let\bcExample\codeexample
\let\ecExample\endcodeexample
\renewenvironment{codeexample}  {\bcExample[]}  {\ecExample}
\let\cExample\codeexample
\let\endcExample\endcodeexample
\newenvironment{eExample}   {\bcExample[]}  {\ecExample}

\begin{document}


When executed, that is, run via |pdflatex| or via |latex| followed by |dvips|,
the resulting will contain something that looks like this:
%
\begin{codeexample}
We are working on
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}.
\end{codeexample}

cExample

%\begin{cExample}
We are working on
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}.
%\end{cExample}

eExample

%\begin{eExample}
We are working on
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}.
%\end{eExample}

\end{document}
```

using `renewenvironment{codeexample}` works, but using `\let\cExample\codeexample` and `\newenvironment{eExample}` to rename/copy the new environment `codeexample` throw errors.

Comment: This code is compiled for me with TexLive 2019, correctly. Do you get compile error?

Comment: @ChenDeng-Ta Can't you reduce this without including the huge `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` which doesn't even appear to be the official one? With `\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox} \newtcblisting{codeexample}[1][]{#1}` instead of the `\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex}`, I see no error either after uncommenting the `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` markers for `cExample` and `eExample`.

Comment: @A-Diyanat and @frougon, I compiled it with XeLaTeX of TeXlive 2019. Error if you uncomment the `cExample` and `eExample` in the body.  I am using `codeexample` extract from pgfmanual, it has syntax highlights. The one by `\newtcblisting{codeexample}` does not have syntax highlights. `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` is beyond my scope, after delete 2 definitions, the `\renewenvironment{codeexample}` works as expected, I am not able to _trim_ the redundant code.

Comment: @ChenDeng-Ta It doesn't matter if the presentation obtained with `\newtcblisting{codeexample}[1][]{#1}` doesn't match your final requirements. What matters to me is to be able to reproduce your error with a minimal example. I've just tried this with XeLaTeX under TL 2019 (with `\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox} \newtcblisting{codeexample}[1][]{#1}` instead of the `\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex}`), this doesn't produce an error and seems to work fine. I hope someone else can reproduce the problem (by the way, double notifications with @ don't work here, unfortunately).

Comment: @frougon, the `newtcblisting{...}`  way is answer in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501284/193369), where the tricks work. Here I am puzzled why the `codeexample` in pgfmanual throws error if using `\codeexample` and `endcodeexample` in `cExample` and `eExample`

Answer (score 1):

I read the code in `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex`. I found that the environment `endcodeexample` is hard coded, which is defined by

1. `\def\codeexample[#1]`
2. `\def\endcodeexample{\endgroup}`
3. `\def\endofcodeexample#1`
4. in line 1502: `\end{codeexample}[|endofcodeexample[#1]]|`

Furthermore, the `codeexample` is hard coded in `pgfmanual.sty` with `pgfmanual.prettyprinter.code.tex` and `pgfmanual.pdflinks.code.tex`

Comment: Most importantly, `\codeexample` looks ahead for `\endcodeexample`, so renaming the beginning might work, but renaming the end will fail.