# How can I show codeboxes?

Tags: formatting

I am in the process of writing a simple manual. In it, I explain how to set up the files and programs necessary to run a pipeline I have written. I would like to include command line commands in that file in a way that makes them stand out and easy to read.

Basically, how can I get this effect in my LaTeX document:

```
cd ~/foo; mkdir bar
```

I was thinking along the lines of a `\parbox` and a background color but I was hoping there might be a class that simplifies this or any other tricks. I don't need code highlighting, I just need an easy way to differentiate commands from prose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the `verbatim` environment since it's straight-forward and should provide the distinction you're after. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I am in the process of writing a simple manual. In it, I explain how to set up the 
files and programs necessary to run a pipeline I have written. I would like to include 
command line commands in that file in a way that makes them stand out and easy to read.

Basically, how can I get this effect in my LaTeX document:
\begin{verbatim}
cd ~/foo; mkdir bar
\end{verbatim}
I was thinking along the lines of a \verb|\parbox| and a background color but I was 
hoping there might be a class that simplifies this or any other tricks. I don't need 
code highlighting, I just need an easy way to differentiate commands from prose.
\end{document}
```

Perhaps defining your own via functionality provided by [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) or [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) could also be an option, as suggested in [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764) and/or [Writing source code in LaTeX as text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167714/5764).

Comment: Wow, I'm currently looking at `fancyrvb` and it's everything I wanted and then some. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As a variation on the `verbatim` theme, the `numberedblock` package allows you to label code blocks with a marginal number, and reference them with `\ref`.  Depending on your application, this may prove useful, too.  (see http://ctan.org/pkg/numberedblock)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numberedblock}
\begin{document}
I am in the process of writing a simple manual. In it, I explain how to set up the 
files and programs necessary to run a pipeline I have written. I would like to include 
command line commands in that file in a way that makes them stand out and easy to read.

Basically, how can I get this effect in my LaTeX document:

\begin{numVblock}[\nbVlabel{nb:A}]
cd ~/foo; mkdir bar
\end{numVblock}

I was thinking along the lines of a \verb|\parbox| and a background color but I was 
hoping there might be a class that simplifies this or any other tricks. I don't need 
code highlighting, I just need an easy way to differentiate commands from prose.

I can number larger blocks

\begin{numVblock}[\nbVlabel{nb:B}]
      program test
      implicit none
      integer a, x
c$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
      a = 0
      x = 1
   10 a = a + x
      if (a .eq. 100) stop
      goto 10
      end
\end{numVblock}

\noindent and can then reference code blocks \ref{nb:A} and \ref{nb:B}.
\end{document}
```

[image]