# Pasting a long text with many special characters into Latex

Tags: verbatim, catcodes

I want to paste a long text with many special characters (&,...) into my Latex doc.

Is there any command to tell Latex to parse this text as it is, rather than parsing it as a Latex source?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Something like the `verbatim` environment? Or `lstlisting` from the `listings` package?

Comment: In fact it depends on the type of document, you have some ways to paste programming languages in a pretty way but they are not the same as with a simple "litterary" text or some maths. It would help to have a precision.

Comment: Some more options are given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167714/writing-source-code-in-latex-as-text?noredirect=1&lq=1