# How to highlight operators and brackets in a C listing?

Tags: color, listings, highlighting

How can I apply a certain style to C (or, well, any other programming language) operators? So that when I write

```
\begin{lstlistings}[language=C++]
    int i = 0;
    if(i > 1) {
        // do something
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

I'll get `=` and `>` (and other operators, and preferably also `(` and `)`, `{` and `}`) highlighted in red, for instance? I managed to treat those characters like other keywords (bold and blue in my case), but this isn't the behavior I want, and it destroys comment definitions.

Comment: What *did* you try?

Comment: Have you looked at `minted`?

Comment: I second @Joseph's suggestion: either Minted or Pygments will probably repay the initial time investment quickly here.  Look at [Syntax Coloring in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex).

Comment: Ok, I have tried only few tricks with listings, I tried to add some emphs, keywords, otherkeywords, etc. Haven't looked at any other package and didn't try to make more "hackish tricks" like the one proposed by Antal S-Z yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround that doesn't break one-line comments and only applies the desired style to operators *outside* comments and strings.

**Caveats**:

- I've had to define all digits as "letters" to prevent my operator style from being applied to them; there may be side effects associated with that.
- Outside comments and strings, the operator style will be applied to all characters that `listings` classifies as "other".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\opstyle{\color{red}} % <--- customise operator style here

\makeatletter

\lstset
{%
  language=C++,
  alsoletter=0123456789,% to prevent \opstyle from being applied to digits
}

% Hook into listings
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\ProcessOther@silmeth}

% helper macro
\newcommand\ProcessOther@silmeth
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\opstyle}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int i = 0;
if(i > 1) && (1/2 < 2) {

    // one-line comment ()={}><;&

    printf("string: ()={}><;&");

    /*
      block comment ()={}><&;
    */
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really do not know HOW EASY you have simplified my work. At first I did not try it because I don't like the `if` statements inside LaTeX and so on, but 4 years later [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442585/how-to-change-style-for-right-parenthesis-inside-lstlisting-environment/442589#comment1110358_442585) suggest me to use your code and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Well, here's a hackish approach with unfortunate code duplication:

```
\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++, literate={\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
                                          {\}}{{\CodeSymbol{\}}}}1
                                          {(}{{\CodeSymbol{(}}}1
                                          {)}{{\CodeSymbol{)}}}1
                                          {>}{{\CodeSymbol{$>$}}}1
                                          {=}{{\CodeSymbol{$=$}}}1
                                          {;}{{\CodeSymbol{$;$}}}1]
    int i = 0;
    if(i > 1) {
        // do something
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

This gives the desired output:

[image: Sample listing.]

The `literate` key is intended to allow you to, for instance, replace the `->` operator with `\to`; here, we're abusing it for highlighting purposes.  It takes a space-separated list of triples, each of the following form: `{SYMBOL}{{REPLACEMENT}}WIDTH`.  Then the listings package will replace each symbol with the replacement, and pretend it occupies *`WIDTH`* characters.  Here, we're just replacing symbols with a highlighted version.  Unfortunately, in my limited testing, I couldn't store that text in a macro, so it looks like it'll have to be put in by hand, which is a lot of grunt work.  Of course, it can be specified once per document in an `\lstset{...}`, but even so.  I imagine the reason things like `keyword` and `emph` don't work—or, at least, didn't in my testing—is that they only accept *words*, and not *symbols*.  However, it is possible to create different keyword and emph classes using `emph={[2]emphasize,this}, emphstyle={[2]\color{red}}`.  Also, I was a little vague/imprecise about some of the syntax here, so be sure to check out [the manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's kind of solution. I'll search in manual for other, maybe nicer, one, but at least this one works.

Comment: There are, howver, some problems: when I highlight "/" this way, then comments don't work (and I can't force them using eg. "morecomment" options), and, I don't understand why, I can't highlight "&".

Comment: Yeah, it's not pretty, but it does the job.  Minted's very nice, as Joseph Wright said, though it is slower.  As for your specific questions: you can highlight `&` just fine, but since it's a special character, you need to escape it like the braces, and specify `{\&}{{\CodeSymbol{\&}}}1`.  As for `/`, though… :-/  I can't see a good way to fix that, other than saying "don't divide anything".