# listings package-Problem with formatting the parenthesis

Tags: formatting, listings

In the following code, I've one problem with the formatting of closing parenthesis. I don't know why.

I give this long testing and uggly code because with smaller ones I've no trouble.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

% == PACKAGES USED == %

\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{listings}

% == EXTRA == %

% C-Verbatim abstract macros
\makeatletter
    \newcommandx\@verbItInColor[3][%
        1=codeColorNormal,%
        2=codeColorBack,%
        3=codeColorBorder
    ]{%
        \ifx\relax#1\relax
            \edef\txt@color{colorInlineCodeNormal}%
        \else
            \edef\txt@color{#1}%
        \fi
        \ifx\relax#2\relax
            \edef\bck@color{colorInlineCodeBack}%
        \else
            \edef\bck@color{#2}%
        \fi
        \ifx\relax#3\relax
            \edef\border@color{colorInlineCodeBorder}%
        \else
            \edef\border@color{#3}%
        \fi
        \Collectverb{\@@myverb{\txt@color}{\bck@color}{\border@color}}%
    }

    \def\@@myverb#1#2#3#4{%
        \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{#1}}%
        \fboxrule=\inlineCodeBorderWidth%
        \ifnum\inlineCodeBorderWidth=0
            \fboxsep=0pt%
        \else
            \fboxsep=\inlineCodeInnerMargin%
        \fi
        \fcolorbox{#3}{#2}{\vphantom{Mg}\lstinline|#4|}%
    }
\makeatother

% == DEF : all the specifications for languages == %

% So as to have one bold face effect !
%
% Source :
%    * http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

% Sources :
%    * https://groups.google.com/group/fr.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/903edf3522db814f?hl=fr
%    * http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/mettre-un-titre-a-ses-boites-t12446-20.html#p120797
%    * http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/operator-highlighting-using-listings
%    * ????

\makeatletter
% Default settings for listings
    \definecolor{inlineCodeColorNormal}{named}{black}
    \definecolor{inlineCodeColorBack}{gray}{0.95}
    \definecolor{inlineCodeColorBorder}{named}{black}

    \newlength{\inlineCodeBorderWidth}
    \setlength{\inlineCodeBorderWidth}{0pt}
    \newlength{\inlineCodeInnerMargin}
    \setlength{\inlineCodeInnerMargin}{2pt}

    \definecolor{codeColorNormal}{named}{black}
    \definecolor{codeColorBack}{gray}{0.95}
    \definecolor{codeColorBorder}{named}{black}

    \newlength{\codeBorderWidth}
    \setlength{\codeBorderWidth}{0pt}
    \newlength{\codeInnerMargin}
    \setlength{\codeInnerMargin}{2pt}

% Restore the default settings for listings
    \newcommand{\codeDefaultSettings}{
        \definecolor{inlineCodeColorNormal}{named}{black}
        \definecolor{inlineCodeColorBack}{gray}{0.95}
        \definecolor{inlineCodeColorBorder}{named}{black}

        \setlength{\inlineCodeBorderWidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\inlineCodeInnerMargin}{2pt}

        \definecolor{codeColorNormal}{named}{black}
        \definecolor{codeColorBack}{gray}{0.95}
        \definecolor{codeColorBorder}{named}{black}

        \setlength{\codeBorderWidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\codeInnerMargin}{2pt}
    }

% Change colors for codes
    \newcommandx\changeCodeColor[3][%
        1=codeColorNormal,%
        2=codeColorBack,%
        3=codeColorBorder
    ]{%
        \ifx\relax#1\relax
            \edef\txt@color{codeColorNormal}%
        \else
            \edef\txt@color{#1}%
        \fi
        \ifx\relax#2\relax
            \edef\bck@color{codeColorBack}%
        \else
            \edef\bck@color{#2}%
        \fi
        \ifx\relax#3\relax
            \edef\border@color{codeColorBorder}%
        \else
            \edef\border@color{#3}%
        \fi
        \colorlet{codeColorNormal}{\txt@color}
        \colorlet{codeColorBack}{\bck@color}
        \colorlet{codeColorBorder}{\border@color}
    }

% Frame for blocks of listings
    \mdfdefinestyle{codeFrameStyle}{
        backgroundcolor   = codeColorBack,%
        linecolor         = codeColorBorder,%
        linewidth         = \codeBorderWidth,%
        innerleftmargin   = \codeInnerMargin,%
        innerrightmargin  = \codeInnerMargin,%
        innertopmargin    = \codeInnerMargin,%
        innerbottommargin = \codeInnerMargin,%
    }

    \newcommand{\backreturn}{\mbox{\rotatebox[y=0.9ex]{180}{\color{red} $\Lsh$}}}

    \lstdefinestyle{default}{%
% Colorss
        basicstyle      = \ttfamily\color{codeColorNormal},
        backgroundcolor   = \color{codeColorBack},%
% Number for lines
        numbers           = left,          % Where to put the line-numbers
        numberstyle       = \footnotesize, % Size of the fonts used for the line-numbers
        stepnumber        = 1,             % Step between two numbers
        numbersep         = 7pt,           % How far the line-numbers are from the code
% Back returns for long lines
        breaklines        = false,         % Bug with inline mode !
        breakatwhitespace = false,         % Automatic breaks only happen at whitespace ?
        breakindent       = 0pt,           % Space before the text of a break
        postbreak         =                % Character used at the begining of a break
            {\,\,\backreturn\,}, %
% You can use a character at the end of line where there is one break.
%    * prebreak=\mbox{\tiny$\searrow$},
%
%  Spacings and tabs
        showstringspaces  = false,         % Underline spaces within strings
        tabsize           = 4,             % Default tabsize to 4 spaces
%   tab               = {%
%       \leavevmode\vrule width0.2pt height 1ex depth 0.8pt
%       \vrule width 1.7em height0.4pt depth 0.8pt
%       \vrule width0.2pt height 1ex depth 0.8pt%
%   }, %
% Escaping character used to allow LaTeX formatting inside one listing.
        escapechar        = \⠶,%
% Playing with colors
%  * Comment
        commentstyle      = \itshape\color{orange},
%  * String
        stringstyle       = \itshape\color{olive},
%  * Test, loop
        keywordstyle      = [1]\bfseries\color{red},
%  * Function
        keywordstyle      = [2]\bfseries\color{blue},
%  * Type
        keywordstyle      = [3]\bfseries\color{green},
%  * Constant
        keywordstyle      = [4]\CodeConstant,
%  * Local functions
        keywordstyle      = [5]\bfseries\color{ProcessBlue},
%  * Local constants
        keywordstyle      = [6]\bfseries\color{gray},
    }

    \newcommand{\CodeConstant}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
    \newcommand{\CodePonctuation}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

% Redefinition of some languages
%
% Here we use more colors but not too much.
    \lstdefinelanguage{python}{%
% Source-TeXgraph : http://texgraph.tuxfamily.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=275&p=2659&hilit=Voil%C3%A0+c%27est+fait#p2663
% Source-Python : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1207390/autres-langages/python-zope/general-python/grouper-mots-cles-langage-python-categories/
%
% --- SPECIAL WORDS - Start --- %
%
%  * Test, loop
        classoffset=0,
        morekeywords={
            if,elif,else,
            is,not,and,or,
            for,in,while,
            assert,try,except,finally
        },
%  * Function, class
        classoffset=1,
        morekeywords={
            from,import,as,
            global,nonlocal,
            class,def,
            del,
            exec,lambda,
            print,
            return,yield,
            with,access,raise,
            continue,pass,break,
        },
%  * Type
%  * Constant
        classoffset=2,
        morekeywords={
            True,False,
            None
        },
%  * Local functions
        classoffset=3,
        alsoletter={@_},
        morekeywords={
            @decorator,
            abs,dict,help,min,setattr,
            all,dir,hex,next,slice,
            any,divmod,id,object,sorted,
            ascii,enumerate,input,oct,staticmethod,
            bin,eval,int,open,str,
            bool,exec,isinstance,ord,sum,
            bytearray,filter,issubclass,pow,super,
            bytes,float,iter,print,tuple,
            callable,format,len,property,type,
            chr,frozenset,list,range,vars,
            classmethod,getattr,locals,repr,zip,
            compile,globals,map,reversed,__import__,
            complex,hasattr,max,round, 
            delattr,hash,memoryview,set,
        },
%  * Types
        classoffset=4,
        morekeywords={
            typeInt
        },
%  * Local constants
        classoffset=4,
        morekeywords={
            NotImplemented,Ellipsis,__debug__
        },
% --- SPECIAL WORDS - END --- %
        classoffset=0,
% Symbols
        literate=
        {>}{{\CodeSymbol{>}}}1
                 {<}{{\CodeSymbol{<}}}1
                 {+}{{\CodeSymbol{+}}}1
                 {*}{{\CodeSymbol{*}}}1
                 {==}{{\CodeSymbol{= =}}}1
                 {=}{{\CodeSymbol{=}}}1
% Ponctuations
                 {]}{{\CodePonctuation{]}}}1
                 {[}{{\CodePonctuation{[}}}1
                 {(}{{\CodePonctuation{(}}}1
                 {)}{{\CodePonctuation{)}}}1
                 {:}{{\CodePonctuation{:}}}1
                 {,}{{\CodePonctuation{,}}}1,
% Sensitive to case
        sensitive=true,%
% Comments
        morecomment=[l]\#,%
% String
        morestring=[b]',%
        morestring=[b]",%
        morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text
        morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""}%
    }%

    \lstdefinelanguage{pythonPlus}[]{python}{%
%  * Constant
        classoffset=2,
        morekeywords={
            Plus
        },
        classoffset=0
    }%

    \newcommand\python{%
        \@ifstar{%
            \lstset{language=python, style=default, showspaces=true, showtabs=true}%
            \@verbItInColor%
        }{%
            \lstset{language=python, style=default, showspaces=false, showtabs=false}%
            \@verbItInColor%
        }%
    }

    \lstnewenvironment{codePython}{%
        \lstset{%
            language   = python,%
            style      = default,%
            breaklines = true,%
            showspaces = false,%
            showtabs   = false,%
        }%
    }{%
        \lstset{breaklines=false}%
    }
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{codePython}{%
        \vspace{0.5em}%
        \lstset{%
            basicstyle      = \ttfamily\color{codeColorNormal},%
            backgroundcolor = \color{codeColorBack}%
        }%
        \begin{mdframed}[style=codeFrameStyle]%
        \vspace{-0.7em}%
    }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{codePython}{%
        \vspace{-0.5em}%
        \end{mdframed}%
        \vspace{0.5em}%
    }

    \lstnewenvironment{codePython*}{%
        \lstset{%
            language   = python,
            style      = default,
            breaklines = true,%
            showspaces = true,%
            showtabs   = true,%
        }%
    }{%
        \lstset{breaklines=false}%
    }
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{codePython*}{%
        \vspace{0.5em}%
        \lstset{%
            basicstyle      = \ttfamily\color{codeColorNormal},%
            backgroundcolor = \color{codeColorBack}%
        }%
        \begin{mdframed}[style=codeFrameStyle]%
        \vspace{-0.7em}%
    }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{codePython*}{%
        \vspace{-0.5em}%
        \end{mdframed}%
        \vspace{0.5em}%
    }



    \lstnewenvironment{codePythonPlus}{%
        \lstset{%
            language   = pythonPlus,
            style      = default,
            breaklines = true,%
            showspaces = false,%
            showtabs   = false,%
        }%
    }{%
        \lstset{breaklines=false}%
    }
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{codePythonPlus}{%
        \vspace{0.5em}%
        \lstset{%
            basicstyle      = \ttfamily\color{codeColorNormal},%
            backgroundcolor = \color{codeColorBack}%
        }%
        \begin{mdframed}[style=codeFrameStyle]%
        \vspace{-0.7em}%
    }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{codePythonPlus}{%
        \vspace{-0.5em}%
        \end{mdframed}%
        \vspace{0.5em}%
    }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Python}

\python+for i in range(9):# Une Boucle+ est du code dans une ligne,
et voici ci-dessous du code sur plusieurs lignes.

\begin{codePython}
@decorator
while(True):
    # Une boucle infinie
    print("Du texte, toujours et encore ==")

typeInt a = 6
typeInt a += 7

b = [a, a**2]

if a == b:
    print('N\'importe quoi !')
else:
    return None
\end{codePython}

Le même code avec tous les espaces visibles.

\begin{codePython*}
while(True):
    # Une boucle infinie
    print("Du texte, toujours et encore")
\end{codePython*}


\begin{codePythonPlus}
while(True): Plus
    # Une boucle infinie
    print("Du texte, toujours et encore")
\end{codePythonPlus}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really heavy. The problem occurs by the option `breaklines=true`. This is the whole magic ;-). `listings` changes the catcode of `)` if you will use this option. So the option `literate` fails.