# Print blue brackets in one language and black in another

Tags: macros, listings, code

In addition to that question i wonder if it is possible to have that settings for one language and default settings for another ?
[How to highlight operators and brackets in a C listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/how-to-highlight-operators-and-brackets-in-a-c-listing/176662#176662)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\opstyle{\color{red}} % <--- customise operator style here

\makeatletter

\lstset
{%
  language=C++,
  alsoletter=0123456789,% to prevent \opstyle from being applied to digits
}

% Hook into listings
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\ProcessOther@silmeth}

% helper macro
\newcommand\ProcessOther@silmeth
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\opstyle}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int i = 0;
if(i > 1) && (1/2 < 2) {

    // one-line comment ()={}><;&

    printf("string: ()={}><;&");

    /*
      block comment ()={}><&;
    */
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here, I want the group other to appear in Black again. How can I do this?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int i = 0;
if(i > 1) && (1/2 < 2) {

    // one-line comment ()={}><;&

    printf("string: ()={}><;&");

    /*
      block comment ()={}><&;
    */
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. That is, show a listing with more than one language and include the code that colors the brackets.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way would be to define a `style` and use that style only when desired. However without this is set up you can use

```
\renewcommand\opstyle{\color{blue}}
```

before the listing to change it as desired:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\opstyle{\color{red}} % <--- customise operator style here

\makeatletter

\lstset
{%
  language=C++,
  alsoletter=0123456789,% to prevent \opstyle from being applied to digits
}

% Hook into listings
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\ProcessOther@silmeth}

% helper macro
\newcommand\ProcessOther@silmeth
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\opstyle}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int i = 0;
if(i > 1) && (1/2 < 2) {

    // one-line comment ()={}><;&

    printf("string: ()={}><;&");

    /*
      block comment ()={}><&;
    */
}
\end{lstlisting}

\renewcommand\opstyle{\color{blue}}
I want the group other to appear in Black again. 
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int i = 0;
if(i > 1) && (1/2 < 2) {

    // one-line comment ()={}><;&

    printf("string: ()={}><;&");

    /*
      block comment ()={}><&;
    */
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```