# Syntax Issues with lstdefinelanguage

Tags: listings, packages

I have some issues defining a new language for the lstlisting package. The source code shall look like this in the end:

[image: Code]

And my latex definition looks like this atm:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{ST}
{
    % list of keywords
    morekeywords={
        case,of,if,then,end_if,end_case,super,function_block,extends,var,
        constant, byte,,end_var,var_input, real,bool,var_output,
        dint,udint,word,dword,array, of,uint,not,adr
    },
    otherkeywords={
    :, :=, <>,;,\,.,\[,\],\^
    },
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l]{//}, 
    morecomment=[s]{(*}{*)},
    morestring=[b]"
    morestring=[b]' 
}

\lstset{
    language=ST,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\color{purple},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{red!50!brown},
    stringstyle=\color{yellow},
    tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
     FUNCTION_BLOCK Name EXTENDS Name2
     VAR CONSTANT
     (*
     multi line comment
     *)
     variable   : BYTE := 2#11111110;
     //variable2 : REAL := 16#AF;
     array: ARRAY[0..1] OF Name3;
     END_VAR

    CASE Variable OF
    0:  
        IF SUPER^.init() THEN
            variable := %QX3.1;
        END_IF
    1:  
        variable := FALSE;  
    END_CASE

    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Besides the color which i can adjust later, how can i tell the compiler to color all digits (and even the # sign as well as TRUE and FALSE) also round brackets and dots aren't colored yet.

I guess i don't have to list all the differences. Can someone help me to adjust this?

Comment: Try this for the brackets: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/how-to-highlight-operators-and-brackets-in-a-c-listing And this for the digits: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package