# How to change style for right parenthesis inside lstlisting environment

Tags: color, listings

Please consider the following MWE (taken from [Antal Spector-Zabusky answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5624/152550)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{miestilo}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    numberstyle=\noncopynumber,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}}   % Code associated to defining styles

\lstset {%
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true,
  style=miestilo,
    language=C++,
  literate=%
        {\&}{{\CodeSymbol{\&}}}1
        {<}{{\CodeSymbol{$<$}}}1
        {(}{{\CodeSymbol{(}}}1
        {)}{{\CodeSymbol{)}}}1                              % This DOES NOT work good
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Example: & works good, < and ( too...
(...)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Right parenthesis error]

If possible, I would like to change the color of the right parenthesis in the same way. Anyway with this method it is not possible for me.

I think I tried all the possibilites:

```
{\)}{{\CodeSymbol{\)}}}1            % Does not work
{)}{{\CodeSymbol{$)$}}}1            % Does not work
{)}{{\CodeSymbol{\)}}}1             % Does not work
{$)$}{{\CodeSymbol{$)$}}}1          % Does not work
% ...
```

but none of these works.

Also I looked at the manual but I can not find anything.

How can it be solved?

Thank you!!

**EDIT: Also it does not work with `/`.**

**EDIT 2: Also it does not work with `.`.**

Comment: I guess you got your code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5624/121799). In this answer it seems to work. There is also an [alternative answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163800/121799), did you try that one? Otherwise you may want to replace the closing bracket by something that gets translated to the bracket...

Comment: Yep, I got my code from there. I didn't try that solution because it includes `if` statements and so on and I don't like it very much... :P. Let me try it.

Comment: YAAAAAAAY in a indirect way you solved it marmot!! Did you know about this package? Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear! ;-) Which package? `minted`?

Comment: No, `listings` (are you a programmer?)

Comment: No, I am a marmot. ;-)

Comment: Shhh, you are a smart marmot. Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/how-to-highlight-operators-and-brackets-in-a-c-listing/163800#comment1110367_163800).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\lstdefinestyle{miestilo}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    numberstyle=\noncopynumber,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
%    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
```

[image]

There is something fishy with that option ...

Comment: It is so strange...

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why this is but here is an ugly workaround. Just prepend another symbol to the brackets, `~` in the example below, and this seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{miestilo}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    numberstyle=\noncopynumber,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}}   % Code associated to defining styles

\lstset {%
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true,
  style=miestilo,
    language=C++,
  literate={\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
           {\}}{{\CodeSymbol{\}}}}1
           {(}{{\CodeSymbol{(}}}1
           {~)}{{\CodeSymbol{)}}}1
           {>}{{\CodeSymbol{$>$}}}1
           {=}{{\CodeSymbol{$=$}}}1
           {;}{{\CodeSymbol{$;$}}}1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Example: & works good, < and ( too...
(...~)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is another comment: if you get your code from somewhere else, [it is always better to disclose the source](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7725/121799).