# How can I display nested lists (the programming-datastructure) in LaTeX?

Tags: programming

I would like to write something in LaTeX, where I need nested lists. It should be displayed like this:

```
segment = [
             [ [0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0] ]
             [ [1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1] ]
             [ [0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,0,0] ]
           ]
```

How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Do you want syntax highlighting?

Comment: No, thats not needed. Thanks for your answer, its a perfect solution to my problem. I didn't \usepackage{verbatim}, though it worked. Do you know why?

Comment: It's probably loaded by one of the other packages you are using. If you want syntax highlighting it's not hard to achieve. Checkout http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose whatever you want displayed in the environment `verbatim` of the `verbatim` package and it will preserve spaces. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
segment = [
             [ [0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0] ]
             [ [1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1] ]
             [ [0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,0,0] ]
           ]
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```