# Text editor highlighting in a verbatim-like environment?

Tags: color, listings, verbatim, code, text-decorations

This might be a long shot, but I'm planning to include a roughly 300-line block of python code as an appendix to my undergraduate thesis, and I was wondering if there's a way to make it display with colored highlighting the way it would in Emacs or another text editor. I just find that I personally can't read code well when it's not colored, so I don't want to inflict that upon the reader. I know about the fancyvrb package, but I don't want to go through character by character and declare colors for everything, and as far as I can tell that would be the only way to use it to get the desired effect.

Comment: listings or minted package, perhaps minted is most natural in this case as it uses the pygmentize python library to apply the syntax highlighting,

Comment: «I'm planning to include a roughly 300-line block of python code»  Just don't.  Nobody wants to read printed out code.

Comment: @HenriMenke I actually agree with you, but the program is about half of the original work that I've done for my thesis, so my advisor says I should include it as an appendix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax Coloring in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex)